# Mutate multiple columns with the same function (transformation) in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create new columns by applying the same transformation to a number of columns.

Example code would be:

```
df %>% 
mutate(
   use_ = case_when(
      use %in% c(1, 2, 3) ~ 0,
      use %in% c(4, 5) ~ 1),
    complex_ = case_when(
      complex %in% c(1, 2, 3) ~ 0,
      complex %in% c(4, 5) ~ 1),
    easy_ = case_when(
      easy %in% c(1, 2, 3) ~ 0,
      easy %in% c(4, 5) ~ 1)
)
```

I'm actually trying to replicate in R something that SAS does easily with arrays. Example code below:

```
array orig (*)  use complex easy;
array new  (*)  use_ complex_ easy_;

  do i=1 to dim(new);
  if orig(i)=. then new(i)=.;
  else if orig(i) in (1,2,3) then new(i)=0;
  else if orig(i) in (4,5) then new(i)=1;
  end;
  drop i;
```

I created a function

```
recoding_fn <- function(a){
     a_ = case_when(
      a %in% c(1, 2, 3) ~ 0,
      a %in% c(4, 5) ~ 1
      )
    
    return(a_)
}
```

and when I apply to one column, it works but the column name becomes "recoding_fn(use)" which is not quite what I want.

```
df %>% 
mutate(recoding_fn(use))
```

The other issue is how can I apply the function (or any other strategy for that matter) so it does the recoding for the three columns I'm interested in (use, complex, easy).

Is this something that can be done within mutate?

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to learn what `mutate` does. Rarely will you use `mutate` in another `mutate`. You need to use `mutate(across(...))` or `mutate_all(..)`

Comment: `library(dplyr); data.frame(use = 1:5, complex = 5:1) %>% mutate(across(c(use, complex), ~recoding_fn(.)))`

Comment: @JonSpring that does it. Thanks! But any changes in there where I could create new the new transformed columns as opposed to overwrite the original ones? Thanks so much for your input!

Comment: `... %>% mutate(across(c(use, complex), ~recoding_fn(.), .names = "{.col}_new"))`

Comment: @JonSpring all I have to say is THANK YOU! Truly appreciated and learned a lot from you today. Thanks!

Comment: Could you pull together all the help from Jon's comments and post an answer so that others may benefit from your question?

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @JonSpring for this answer:

```r
library(dplyr)
data.frame(use = 1:5, complex = 5:1) %>% 
    mutate(across(c(use, complex), ~recoding_fn(.), .names = "{.col}_new"))
```